# How to add record to "through" table in Sequelize

Tags: node.js, express, sequel

I have this User Model

```
'use strict';
const { Model } = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class User extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
      User.belongsToMany(models.Programs, { through: 'UserPrograms' })
    }
  };
  User.init({
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    username: DataTypes.STRING,
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'User',
    paranoid: true
  });
  return User;
};
```

And I have a program model

```
'use strict';
const { Model } = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Programs extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      Programs.belongsToMany(models.User, { through: 'UserPrograms' })
    }
  };
  Programs.init({
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'Programs',
    paranoid: true
  });
  return Programs;
};
```

When I create a user, I send an array with some program ids (they exist in the program table) and I want to be able to "assign" those programs to the user that I'm creating. But I don't know the correct syntax. The documentation talks about creating a new record for the second table (program in my case) but it doesn't say anything about creating it with an id that already exists (at least I didn't find anything, I looked here https://sequelize.org/master/manual/advanced-many-to-many.html)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. First I added the user as I normally would, then with the user object that is created, I did the following

```
//Create user programs
programs.map(async(v) => {
    const program = await db.Programs.findByPk(v.ProgramId);
    newUser.addProgram(program);
})
```

It worked perfectly.